# Free fall movement with air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

> For small free-falling particles in the atmosphere, the air resistance is proportional to the velocity (orienting the y axis vertically downwards, is of the form $-\rho y'(t)$, with $\rho > 0$. Consider the free fall of such a particle from an initial position $y_{0}$ and an initial velocity $v_{0}$ (vertical), taking into account the weight force. Determine $y(t)$.
>
> Hint: Look for a particular solution of the differential equation of motion, which is inhomogeneous. For this, take into account that for long times the particle tends to fall at a constant velocity (why?), The so-called terminal velocity.

My attempt:

We have:
$$my''(t) = mg - \rho y'(t)$$
Then we have a 2nd order ode (homogeneous). Now just solve the edo. Is this right?
Thank you!!

Comment: Note that it isn't free fall if there is air resistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a correct approach, given the problem statement. However, it's not homogeneous. The homogeneous version of it would be $my''(t) = -\rho y'(t)$ or $my''(t)+\rho y'(t)=0$. Representing the differential operator with $D$, that's $(mD^2+\rho D)y=0$. From a linear algebra point of view, if we take $A=mD^2+\rho D$, then $A$ is a linear operator, and the homogeneous version of the equation is $Ay=0$, while the inhomogeneous version is $Ay=mg$. You can then apply many of the principles from linear algebra that would apply if $A$ were a matrix.

BTW, for the force is generally proportional to the square of the velocity, but depending on such factors as the size of the objects, it can be treated as being proportional to just the velocity, which gives an ODE that is easier to solve. For the purposes of this problem, you can simply take what your instructor has told as the problem to solve, but you shouldn't use this for falling objects in general.

Comment: The force is proportional to the velocity (not the square) for low Reynolds numbers. This applies to dust particles in air and even to very small insects (though they are not "free-falling" when they are flying, of course). For  objects a few mm in diameter or larger, the resistance is *not* proportional to velocity in most situations.

Comment: *In reality, the force is proportional to the square of the velocity, but apparently your instructor has decided to simplify the equation to focus on the mechanics of using ODEs to solve physics problems* Isn't it so that the drag force is proportional to $y'$ for low $\mathbf{Re}$ and proportional $y'^2$ for higher $\mathbf{Re}$ (laminar v. turbulent)?

Comment: The standard lab experiment to measure viscosity by dropping an object in a column of liquid is another example of "Stokes flow" where the resistance is proportional to velocity, and in the experimental situation Re is about 1 (compared with $10^6$ or greater for many flow situations in air).

Comment: @alephzero 'Laminar falls' must be possible for very light objects with high drag coefficients $C_D$.